# How to design an HTML Table with different rowspan?

Tags: html, html-table, rows

I've been designing webpages for some time now, and for one of my webpages, I need to design a table with 6 columns and 3 rows. The first column need to have 3 rows, while the other 5 columns only need 2 rows. I can make it using this CODE:

```
<tr><td class="style3">7:00 AM
                </td>
                <td class="style3" rowspan="2">
                </td>
                <td class="style3" rowspan="2">
                </td>
                <td class="style3" rowspan="2">
                </td>
                <td class="style3" rowspan="2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td class="style3">7:30 AM
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td class="style3">7:59 AM
                </td>
                <td class="style3">
                </td>
                <td class="style3">
                </td>
                <td class="style3">
                </td>
                <td class="style3">
                </td>
            </tr>
```

How can I make it so that the **bottom border of the first row of the 5 columns** are **exactly in the middle** of the **second row of the first column**?

It means that **the line of the bottom border of the first row of the 5 columns is in the middle of the value *"7:30 AM"* from the first column, second row**. I know it is quite confusing but I cannot show you an image of how I want it to look like because I just join here and I don't have 10 reputations to post an image. Please understand my logic.

Answer (score 0):

`rowspan=2` means, the column will span two rows, hence if you are applying this to the first column of the first row, the the next row should have one less column. For every column you do a `rowspan="n"` on, you need to omit that column from the next "n-1" number of rows.

The following snippet will make it clear to you:

```css
table, td { 
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td { padding: 8px; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">7:00 AM</td>
            <td class="style3" rowspan="2">Event 1</td>
            <td class="style3" rowspan="2">Event 2</td>
            <td class="style3" rowspan="2">Event 3</td>
            <td class="style3" rowspan="2">Event 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3" rowspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3" rowspan="2">Event 5</td>
            <td class="style3" rowspan="2">Event 6</td>
            <td class="style3" rowspan="2">Event 7</td>
            <td class="style3" rowspan="2">Event 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">7:59 AM</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But as I said in my post, the first column has 3 rows and the rest only has 2 columns. In your example, what I want is to put the bottom line of 7:00 AM in the middle of Location 1, Location 2, and so on.

Comment: I am unable to understand. Could you please draw a layout and add to your question.

Comment: Actually, I already have the layout, I just can't upload it yet 'cause I am new here, and I need atleast 10 reputations. That, I don't have.

Comment: You could upload it to anywhere, dropbox, flikr etc.. and post a link.

Comment: @ReymarkGarciaFlorentino: Updated the code in the answer. The explanation remains the same. For every column you do a `rowspan="n"` on, you need to omit that column from the next "n-1" number of rows.